# error Vertical viewport was given unbounded height

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

How can i have a dynamic listview and some static rows?
I want to create a page thats about a product of company and customer check their products, about,at the first of page i have some details rows like Destination,wieght,.... for a product and the bottom of that 
i have a vertical timeline for showing more details,but i have some error,how can i solve it?

```
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
          child: new ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Flexible(
                child: new ListView(children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Text("Package Details",
                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    color: Color(0xffd01818),
                                    fontSize: 25.0,
                                  )),
                              new Container(
                                //padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0),
                                child: new Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    new Expanded(
                                        child: new Container(
                                            padding:
                                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                                  Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                              color: Color(0xffffe88e),
                                            ),
                                            child: new Row(
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                new Text(
                                                  "Packages Count:",
                                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ))),
                                    new Expanded(
                                        child: new Container(
                                            padding:
                                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                                  Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                              color: Color(0xffff25b43),
                                            ),
                                            child: new Row(
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                new Text(
                                                  "istanbul (IST)",
                                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ))),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              new Container(
                                padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                                child: new Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    new Expanded(
                                        child: new Container(
                                            padding:
                                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                                  Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                              color: Color(0xffffe88e),
                                            ),
                                            child: new Row(
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                new Text(
                                                  "Payment Method:",
                                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ))),
                                    new Expanded(
                                        child: new Container(
                                            padding:
                                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                                  Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                              color: Color(0xffff25b43),
                                            ),
                                            child: new Row(
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                new Text(
                                                  '2',
                                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ))),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              new Container(
                                // padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                                child: new Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    new Expanded(
                                        child: new Container(
                                            padding:
                                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                                  Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                              color: Color(0xffffe88e),
                                            ),
                                            child: new Row(
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                new Text(
                                                  "Origin:",
                                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ))),
                                    new Expanded(
                                        child: new Container(
                                            padding:
                                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                                  Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                              color: Color(0xffff25b43),
                                            ),
                                            child: new Row(
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                new Text(
                                                  "2",
                                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ))),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                ]),
              ),
              new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return new Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
                            child: new Card(
                              margin: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                              child: new Container(
                                width: double.infinity,
                                height: 200.0,
                                color: Colors.green,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Positioned(
                            top: 0.0,
                            bottom: 0.0,
                            left: 35.0,
                            child: new Container(
                              height: double.infinity,
                              width: 1.0,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Positioned(
                            top: 100.0,
                            left: 15.0,
                            child: new Container(
                              height: 40.0,
                              width: 40.0,
                              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              child: new Container(
                                margin: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                height: 30.0,
                                width: 30.0,
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: 5,
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
      }
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKM8N.jpg
```

Comment: Can you explain more also Add your Screen shot which your vertical view issue

Comment: Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. In this case, a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.

RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#f9759 relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///C

Answer (score 0):

Container should be given height property.

Comment: i added it but i have another error ;(  

Failed assertion: line 263 pos 16: 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index': is not true.

Comment: post the full code so that i can use dartpad to debug it.

Comment: i posted the full code as an answer,plz help me i'm an intern in flutter :(

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

class ShowDetails extends StatefulWidget {
//  var res;
//  ShowDetails({this.res});
  @override
  _ShowDetailsState createState() => _ShowDetailsState();
}

class _ShowDetailsState extends State<ShowDetails> {
//  var data;
//  void initState() {
//    // TODO: implement initState
//    super.initState();
//    data = widget.res['data'];
//  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                  child: new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return new Stack(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
                                child: new Card(
                                  margin: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                  child: new Container(
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    height: 200.0,
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              new Positioned(
                                top: 0.0,
                                bottom: 0.0,
                                left: 35.0,
                                child: new Container(
                                  height: double.infinity,
                                  width: 1.0,
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                ),
                              ),
                              new Positioned(
                                top: 100.0,
                                left: 15.0,
                                child: new Container(
                                  height: 40.0,
                                  width: 40.0,
                                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  child: new Container(
                                    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                    height: 30.0,
                                    width: 30.0,
                                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                        shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                        itemCount: 5,
                      )
                    ],
                  )),
              new Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Text("Package Details",
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                color: Color(0xffd01818),
                                fontSize: 25.0,
                              )),
                          new Container(
                            //padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0),
                            child: new Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Expanded(
                                    child: new Container(
                                        padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                          color: Color(0xffffe88e),
                                        ),
                                        child: new Row(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            new Text(
                                              "Packages Count:",
                                              style: new TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ))),
                                new Expanded(
                                    child: new Container(
                                        padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                          color: Color(0xffff25b43),
                                        ),
                                        child: new Row(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            new Text(
                                              "istanbul (IST)",
                                              style: new TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ))),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Container(
                            padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                            child: new Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Expanded(
                                    child: new Container(
                                        padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                          color: Color(0xffffe88e),
                                        ),
                                        child: new Row(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            new Text(
                                              "Payment Method:",
                                              style: new TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ))),
                                new Expanded(
                                    child: new Container(
                                        padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                          color: Color(0xffff25b43),
                                        ),
                                        child: new Row(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            new Text(
                                              '2',
                                              style: new TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ))),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Container(
                            // padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                            child: new Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Expanded(
                                    child: new Container(
                                        padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                          color: Color(0xffffe88e),
                                        ),
                                        child: new Row(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            new Text(
                                              "Origin:",
                                              style: new TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ))),
                                new Expanded(
                                    child: new Container(
                                        padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                          color: Color(0xffff25b43),
                                        ),
                                        child: new Row(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            new Text(
                                              "2",
                                              style: new TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ))),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            ],
          )

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```